# Cocoapods installation. Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect

Tags: macos, terminal, cocoapods

I have run:

> $ sudo gem install cocoapods

and I get the following output:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
>       Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (https://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/cocoapods-0.36.4.gemspec.rz)

I already ran this command:

> sudo gem update --system

[image: gem update command]

Comment: more explanation added.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58414931/5790492 check this answer