# Сocoapods trunk URL couldn't be downloaded

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoapods, podfile, trunk

I am getting this error when I try to `pod repo update` and `pod install`

> CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded:
> https://cdn.cocoapods.org/deprecated_podspecs.txt, error: Failed to
> open TCP connection to cdn.cocoapods.org:443 (No route to host -
> connect(2) for "cdn.cocoapods.org" port 443)

Does somebody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: In case it helps someone, I had to disable my pi-hole and then it worked. :D

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It seems that it's a cdn problem because when i use proxy the link https://cdn.cocoapods.org/all_pods_versions_e_2_1.txt is opened and when not it return error.

What i did:
`gem uninstall cocoapods`
`gem cleanup`
`rvm osx-ssl-certs update all`

That didn't help.

Then i went to Chrome and opened https://cdn.cocoapods.org/all_pods_versions_e_2_1.txt it was an error. Then i cleared cache but it didn't help. After [switching](https://browsec.com/) to proxy and returning back it started to work.

> Resume: Turn on and switch off the VPN.

Also try to `pod cache clean --all` and `pod setup` by @NightWatcher

Comment: Getting this issue from Russia. Turning ON VPN helped me.

Comment: Voted up. You put me on the right track, disabling OpenDNS worked for me.

Comment: pod cache clean --all worked for me. thanks, @Nik Kov

Comment: It seems that that problem could be because of CDN errors: https://status.cocoapods.org/#month

Answer (score 374):

I got it working by using below commands:

1. `pod repo remove trunk`

   and then
2. `pod install` or `pod update`

Comment: removing the trunk fixed it for me.

Comment: Works for me too, except that I used `pod update` instead of `pod install`.

Comment: It would be good, if you will explain what this command do and what can it affect to.

Comment: `pod install` not works, but `pod update` works for me.

Comment: Works for me only after restarting my PC. :/

Comment: This works for me. But it keeps happening every so often and breaks my build until I ssh into build machine and run `pod repo remove trunk` manually. Why does this happen? Should `pod repo remove trunk` be a build step that is executed every time?

Comment: You do not have permission to delete the trunk repository.Perhaps try prefixing this command with sudo.

Comment: This answer works for me on MacOS

Answer (score 20):

Step one. Remove trunk & master

```
pod repo remove trunk
pod repo remove master
```

Step two. Add source in podfile.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
```

Step three. Run pod update. Solve my problem.

```
pod update --verbose
```

Answer (score 15):

I fixed it by this solution
Add this to your Podfile:

```
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
```

Afterwards, run the following command to remove it from your managed repo list (in console):

```
pod repo remove master
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you have any reference link for this?

Comment: Sorry I don't remember where I found this solution. Hope it helped you

Answer (score 11):

I spend hours by uninstalling and reinstalling pods, Connecting and disconnecting wifi, and trying out different solutions I could find from the internet. And nothing worked. Finally I decided to restart my Macbook and the problem solved. So before trying the solutions given above, I would strongly recommend you to try restarting your system.

Comment: Same here: Cocoopads 1.10.0 failed to download a CDN dependency on the terminal. But I could open the file in a browser just fine. Reboot fixed it!

Comment: old school reboot saved me too

Answer (score 10):

Just try this in your terminal:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: This solved my problem. I was using an older version that apparently had this bug.

Comment: SO answers require some sort of explanation as to what and why we should do the steps in your answer. This is so that people can learn and understand what they are doing. Also, it stops people from tricking others into using dangerous code, etc. Please explain you answer a little, or more.

Answer (score 8):

After checking all the answers and using VPN just to update pods, I've tried:

```
pod repo remove trunk
pod repo remove master
sudo rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos
pod update
```

I'm not specifying this BTW:
`source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'`

And all worked.

Comment: I was using this in CI/CD, so I first had to run the first three commands (with set +e), then freshly start the process with only the fourth one. It started downloading the pods.

Comment: deleting `~/.cocoapods/repos` helped

Answer (score 5):

Based on [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10078#issuecomment-696688386) github comment: whenever cocoapods CDN not working due to DNS issues, try adding directly the url that cdn.cocoapods.org redirects to, as a source in the top level of your `Podfile`:

```
source 'https://cocoapods-cdn.netlify.app/'
```

Comment: This link is no longer a valid option. The url redirects to a blog post indicating that 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org' should be used.

Comment: @PhillHealey just tested the source url in a `Podfile` and seams to work fine. Also the link for the github comment seams to be correct. At which url you are referring to?

Comment: If you go to 'https://cocoapods-cdn.netlify.app/' in a browser it redirects.

Answer (score 5):

Remove Podfile.lock and try re-installing the Pods again (pod install). This worked for me.

Comment: This is the right answer. Deintegrate your pods, delete Podfile.lock and everything started working.

Answer (score 5):

For those, who faced with the following:

> [!] CDN: trunk Repo update failed - 1 error(s):
> CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://...podspec.json Response: 429 429: Too Many Requests

You should remove `Podfile.lock`, `Pod` folder and reconnect to your VPN (if any) then run

`pod install --repo-update`

Comment: I had the same problem and your solution fixed that! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. I followed below steps and it works.

I suggest to restart the system before following below instructions.

Delete Podfile.lock
add `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'` line in Podfile

Then run below commands

```
pod repo remove trunk
sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
pod deintegrate
pod cache clean --all
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod install or pod update
```

Comment: I am getting the same issue right now, and it is because CDN is down, you can check the status here https://status.cocoapods.org/#month

Answer (score 5):

Someone might be checking on this in 2023 so here's what I did (in a React Native project)

```
$ cd ios/
$ pod repo remove trunk
$ pod deintegrate
$ pod cache clean --all
$ pod install
```

Answer (score 3):

On all of those comments; nothing worked for me
So i found this and it worked perfectly for me :

> pod cache clean --all

> pod setup

Answer (score 2):

just remove **Pods** folder and **Podfile.lock**

add

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

to the top
**Podfile**

then clean cache
`pod cache clean --all`

finally update and install pod
`pod install --repo-update`

Answer (score 1):

Tried many solutions from here and there but what worked in my case is:

```
gem uninstall cocoapods 
gem cleanup
sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
```

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 1):

Several of these solutions didn't work for me but it was successful with updating the pods once I disconnected from AnyConnect VPN.

Comment: I'm using `Tunnelblick` and it worked fine after I disconnected. Might be related to DNS issue we have here from time to time. I can open timeouted link in a browser just fine though.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, on Apple Mac with M1:

```
gem uninstall cocoapods
arch -x86_64 brew install cocoapods
arch -x86_64 brew reinstall cocoapods
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tried all above options but nothing fixed my issue. i just switched my internet connection to other service provider and then try pod install and trunk url issue was no more there. so try to switch internet connection if facing trunk url issue.

Comment: Not a solution. removing .cocoapods/ directory as stated by Paresh Mangukiya do works

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue and tried all the answers suggested above. But, the real issue seemed to be with not being able to access the Git repo for Cocoapods:
‘**error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied**’

Executing `sudo chown -R $USER: .`
at
**/Users/user_name/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods**
fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

it's up to proxy servise you've to do is all
first open up your proxy and set it up into your country or turn it off temporarely and
clean your xcode build folder and
try again pod install ro pod update
I hope that'll work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If all the answers did not help, try these steps:

1. Make sure you're in ios folder and list all available pod repos

   pod repo list
2. Iterate over the list and delete all of them

   pod repo remove [repo_name]
3. In any folder on your local machine, clone Cocoapods Github repo

   git clone "https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git"
4. At the top of your podfile, reference only this local repo

   source '/Users/hossamabdelnaser/Specs' # This depends on where you cloned the repo
5. Make sure you're in ios folder and install pods

   pod install

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this issue, when I used VPN every thing was fine!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this problem by using Cloduflare's WARP which is a proxy server

Downloaded from here:

https://1.1.1.1/

Answer (score 0):

If you stuck with this annoying error, here all the solutions in order.

1: Try update cocoapods

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then pod update / install.

2: Remove cocoapods cache

```
pod cache clean --all
pod setup
```

Then pod update / install.

3: Remove cocoapods cache

```
pod repo remove trunk
pod repo remove master
```

Add source in your podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
```

Then pod update / install.

4: Uninstall / reinstall Cocoapods

```
gem uninstall cocoapods
brew install cocoapods
```

Then pod update / install.

5: Try reboot Mac

The last chance...
Then pod update / install.