# CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded in certain React Native project when running "pod install"?

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, cdn

I have this react native project that im working with multiple computers, in my MacBook everything works fine, when I run "pod install" after running "npm install" the pods project is created successfully, in the other hand when I do the same in my desktop I get this following error:

[image]

Ive tried installing pods for other projects and everything works fine, the problem is with this project in particular.

UPDATAE:

Thanks for your comments, for you to know:

after running:

```
pod repo remove trunk
pod install
```

This is what I get:

[image]

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "aksystems",
  "version": "3.9.8",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "ios": "cd ios/ && rm -rf Pods/ && rm -rf Podfile.lock && pod install && cd ../ && react-native run-ios",
    "android": "cd android/ && ./gradlew clean && cd ../ && react-native run-android",
    "build:ios": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/mstore/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'",
    "setup": "./scripts/setup.sh",
    "setup:android": "./scripts/setup_android.sh",
    "reset": "./scripts/reset.sh",
    "postinstall": "patch-package && npx jetify"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.4",
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^0.1.1",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "5.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "^3.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.0.4",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^6.0.4",
    "api-ecommerce": "0.0.34",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "currency-formatter": "^1.5.4",
    "deprecated-react-native-listview": "0.0.6",
    "firebase": "^7.9.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.9.2",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "html-entities": "^1.2.1",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "oauth-1.0a": "^2.2.6",
    "patch-package": "^6.1.2",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-admob": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-apple-authentication": "https://github.com/ton44079/react-native-apple-authentication",
    "react-native-camera": "git+https://git@github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera.git",
    "react-native-clean-form": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^1.10.0",
    "react-native-credit-card-input": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^2.7.7",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-facebook-account-kit": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-fluid-slider": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^2.2.26",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.9.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.5",
    "react-native-localization": "^2.1.4",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.12.4",
    "react-native-modalbox": "2.0.0",
    "react-native-onesignal": "3.5.0",
    "react-native-paper": "3.4.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^6.3.3",
    "react-native-radio-buttons": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.13",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-alpha.22",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "1.0.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-store-rating": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0-nightly.5",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.13.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.0.2",
    "react-native-webview": "8.0.1",
    "react-navigation": "4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.6.2",
    "react-redux": "7.1.0",
    "redux": "4.0.5",
    "redux-actions": "^2.6.5",
    "redux-persist": "5.10.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.20",
    "tipsi-stripe": "^7.5.1",
    "urijs": "^1.19.1",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "url-parse": "^1.4.7",
    "util": "^0.12.1",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "validate.js": "^0.13.1",
    "wpapi": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "eslint": "6.5.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.19.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.3.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.57.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.10.2",
    "reactotron-react-native": "4.0.2",
    "reactotron-redux": "3.1.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupFiles": [
      "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

And podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
#require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'aksystems' do
  # Pods for mstore
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'

  pod 'react-native-date-picker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-date-picker'

  pod 'react-native-image-picker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker'

  pod 'Stripe', '~> 14.0.0'

  pod 'tipsi-stripe', :path => '../node_modules/tipsi-stripe'

  pod 'react-native-onesignal', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-onesignal'

  target 'aksystemsTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end

target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.9.3', '< 3.0'
end
```

As you said, Ive seen in various SO questions and GitHub posts that might be a network issue but as I told you another Pod projects work pretty well, the pods versions are the same (last) and both machines are running over the same network.

Comment: Do you have the latest Cocoapods version on both machines? Can you access [this file](https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/6.3.1/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json) from that machine? That sounds like a network issue. Also why there cocoapods is trying to fetch both `6.3.1` and `6.4.0` versions of `FirebaseAnalytics`? Please add the `Podfile` and the `package.json` contents to your question.

Comment: Thanks @ChristosLytras , added.

Comment: You can check my answer here [Сocoapods trunk URL couldn't be downloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58409725/%D0%A1ocoapods-trunk-url-couldnt-be-downloaded/59943058?noredirect=1#comment111121689_59943058)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thank you all for the support, after multiple efforts to solve this, I found the solution was related to my network making IPV6 requests instead of IPV4, I don't fully understand this but this is how I solved it:

> System Preferences > Network > Advanced > TCP/IP > Configure IPv6:
> Link-local only

[Source](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/2253#issuecomment-432111545)

Answer (score 24):

You could try update the repos because it might not contain what you want. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701352/what-exactly-does-pod-repo-update-do)

```
pod repo update && pod install
```

If that fails, an [example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/blob/master/Objective-C/advanced/APIDemo/Podfile) of the usage of `pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'` adds a source explicitly,

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

**OLD Answer:**

Have you tried `pod repo remove trunk; pod install` as taken from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58409725/%D0%A1ocoapods-trunk-url-couldnt-be-downloaded). It would be useful if you shared your `Podfile`.

This removes a repo called `trunk' from cocoapods, then re-adds it.

[Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/ben-xD/8b1414391a0d7a0709bf5bbf4ec66f00) of my Podfile, which also uses Firebase.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to remove trunk and does not work. Im receiving a similar error: CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.cocoapods.org/deprecated_podspecs.txt, error: execution expired

Comment: @KarloA.López Can you show a screenshot with the new error?

Comment: @MayconMesquita Ive uploaded the image. Thanks

Comment: It worked thanks but 'pod install --repo-update' didn't work, not sure why

Answer (score 3):

CocoaPods 1.8.x offers the ability to use either Git or CDN (default).

You can always fallback to the previous git based implementation by adding to your **Podfile**:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

Based on your last error log, i think this can be useful.

Comment: The CDN is having trouble in come countries and some Shared IP's. You can try a VPN to know if is issue with your network.

Answer (score 3):

after trying many times it was fixed by :
adding this to the top of the podfile ↙️

`source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'`

then do this:

```
pod repo remove trunk
pod install
```

refrence ✅:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9085

Answer (score 1):

```
gem uninstall cocoapods
brew install cocoapods
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the exact same problem. Turns out I compiled a problematic version of `curl` library from source in my operation system with `make install`. This libcurl binary is missing the ability to request https URLs.

So I just `make uninstall` this libcurl and fallback to system's libcurl and everything works fine again.