# CDN: trunk Repo update failed - 12 error(s):

Tags: macos, flutter, cocoapods, fbsdk

Getting error when I tried to update pod,

```
pod update
```

Error found,

```
[!] CDN: trunk Repo update failed - 12 error(s):
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/9/b/5/FBSDKCoreKit/6.1.0-alpha/FBSDKCoreKit.podspec.json Response: Timeout was reached
```

However, I can access the json path smoothly from my browser.

**How to resolve this?**

Comment: I have same issue like yours, I fixed it https://stackoverflow.com/a/76455284/17419694

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I have same issue like yours, I fixed it by running:

`pod repo remove trunk`  and then `pod install`, once these are complete I ran `pod update` and it updated everything.

Answer (score 4):

What works for me is adding the source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' at the top of the pod file as follows:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

then I run this command in the ios root:

```
pod deintegrate && pod repo remove trunk && pod setup && pod install
```

Note: install/update cocoapods first by:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: I update cocoapods repo manually first by the following command
`git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git ~/.cocoapods/repos/master`
then I follow your steps and it works fine, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I got this error with `FirebaseRemoteConfig 7.1.0`.

In my case, above answers didn't work.

- `pod repo remove trunk`
- Add GitHub path to Podfile

But it was resolved after I ate dinner... (maybe caused by CDN server)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue , following steps helped me to fix these errors-

1. comment git path for cocoa pods and add path for CDN
   [image]
2. `pod 'TensorFlowLiteSelectTfOps', '~> 0.0.1-nightly'`
3. `pod repo remove trunk`
4. `pod install`
5. No of errors reduced , keep repeating step 4 until u get no errors and it starts installing pod

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are on mac

just run

```
git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
```

then go do

```
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of things works for you then try to update your cocoapods using

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

It will definitely fix issue. :)

Comment: "definitely," they say...