New Version of Google MLKit/Translate required for iOS Privacy Manifest Fails to Update from Pod
Google just released a new version of MLKit for iOS v 7.0.0 to address the Apple Privacy Manifest mandate.  The new version includes an update to Translate 5.0.0.
However, when I try to run a pod update I get:
[!] CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded:
Analyzing dependencies
https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/b/8/1/MLKitTranslate/5.0.0/MLKitTranslate.podspec.json
Response: Failure when receiving data from the peer

The pod spec file appears to actually be intact at that URL.
Any solutions?

Found the solution, but not the reason why. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58409725/Сocoapods-trunk-url-couldnt-be-downloaded
